# how to zip local folder and download it?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, jszip

I need to compress a local folder in order for the user to download it, this folder is a small web page with sub folders and images in it.

What I need to do is:

1. Create a text file (I already have this)
2. Compress the folder that I want with the text file that I already created (this is where I'm stuck)

I tried with jszip-utils but it wont work.

```
function descargaPlantilla(){
    let zip = new JSZip();
     var filename = "imagenes.html";

    var blob = new Blob([result], {
        type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
    });

    saveAs(blob, filename);  


    SZipUtils.getBinaryContent("/Users/ricardowallacelimon/E4", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err; // or handle the error
        }
        zip.file("/Users/ricardowallacelimon/E4", data, { binary: true });
    });




}
```

I get these errors:

```
TypeError: global.JSZipUtils is undefinedjszip-utils-ie.js:36:1ReferenceError: SZipUtils is not defined4 cenidet.js:180:5

ReferenceError: SZipUtils is not defined
```

Comment: where is `SZipUtils` defined? not in the code you posted - where is `result` defined? Is this server side or browser side code?

Comment: SZipUtils is linked on my html do i have to define on my function? result is a global variable,its a string and its browser side.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel 5, you can use `new ZipArchive`. Example below:

```
private function packIntoZip(Logo $logo, array $files)
{
    $userLogoDir = resource_path('prepared-zip-files/' . $logo->user_id);

    $zipFilePath = $userLogoDir . '/zip-file';
    $this->createFolderIfNotExisting($zipFilePath);

    $zip          = new ZipArchive();
    $zipFileFinal = $zipFilePath . '/wiz_logo.zip';
    $zip->open($zipFileFinal, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
    }

    $zip->addFile($this->informationPdfBasic, basename($this->informationPdfBasic));

    $zip->close();

    return $zipFileFinal;
}
```

And then in controller:

```
public function show(Logo $logo)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $logo);

    $logoFilesDownloader = new LogoFilesDownloader();
    $file = $logoFilesDownloader->prepareZip($logo);

    return Response::download($file);
}
```

Hope it will help! Happy coding :)